# Is it legal to decompile an APK and use part of its code in your app

Tags: decompiling

Is it legal to decompile an apk and use part of it's code? (more specifically: a URL connector (I haven't learned that yet)).

The rest of the app (layouts and such) is made by me. Can I publish this app without being concerned on the legal front?

Comment: Don't take this as legal advice(as I am not a lawyer), but you should be fine. As you haven't copied the entire app and try to pass it off as your work, you aren't violating any policies. Though, you may be better off **recreating** the URL connector based on the decompiled code. But something to keep in mind is that when you use say a single method, there is no way to confirm you didn't create it. And as time passes and your needs change, you may edit it and make the method completely different from what it originally was when you decompiled the app. Decompiling itself isn't illegal though.

Answer (score 28):

Decompiling is absolutely LEGAL, regardless of what the shills say. At most, you can be sued for unauthorized activity relating to software unless you're redistributing it. Courts in the U.S. have always upheld the right of users to know exactly what code is being installed on their systems by programs they have legitimately obtained.

People REALLY need to quit saying "ILLEGAL" unless they know what they're talking about. There is absolutely NO law in the U.S. that states you cannot copy for private purposes or decompile software. Companies have tried to sue to stop it, but; a) that's only civil, not criminal, and therefore not ILLEGAL; and b) they've only won when the content was given to an outside party from whom the companies did not receive payment. IE the person has been shown to break the law.

Comment: What you state about decompiling being legal is wholly correct, and I would agree that the top-voted answer is worded incorrectly. However, the question was not only is it OK to decompile - but is it OK to them *use that code* in their own program.

Comment: While true, this doesn't address the last part of the question which says "Can I publish this app without being concerned on the legal front?"

Comment: Not sure it's LEGAL. It also appears in applications EULA, so it seems universal. see EULA of whatsapp for example: whatsapp.com/legal/#terms-of-service (search decompile)

Comment: Ransh, EULA is not a law, thus does not form the basis for law. It is a contract, thus forms the basis for a civil agreement. They can sue you for violating it, but not press charges against you for violating it. The courts then can decide if it's a valid contract agreement. As for the question "Can I publish code that was produced from decompiling other code" compiling code often removes and rearranges code patterns, and much of what is copyrightable is lost. It could be argued that the resulting machine code, and the decompiled code is not able to be copyrighted, but ask that of the courts.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the application license but in general, if decompilation is necessary that means that the author does not allow the use of its code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know in simple words"It absolutely LEGAL decompiling apks,but it is ILLEGAL to use that code in making something identical to the original one".

You can learn from the code but who can't copy there work..(It sometimes depends on publishers Copyrights).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR No.

You can decompile it but you can't use the code.

Answer (score -31):

Decompiling is both illegal and wrong, unless it's your own work.

You can learn what you need on Google, or find open-source stuff using it and learn from that.

It's illegal to decompile ANYTHING without permission.

Comment: Fur future reference: It is not illegal to **decompile** the app. It is, however, illegal if you decode it, take all the source code, maybe change the graphics, package and some other things and try to pass it off as your own app. It is illegal redistribution of a copyrighted work. Decompiling an app and using a minor part of the code, as long as it isn't a major part of the app. say you copy redistribute the entire app: that would be illegal. If you decode the app to see how it works and try to learn from that experience, perhaps creating a clone of it to learn something that may not be (1/2)

Comment: well documented anywhere, there is no harm in it. As far as I know(after doing a lot of research), there are **no laws prohibiting decompiling apps on any platform**. Redistributing the app, however, goes under the law of piracy unless the app has a license that allows redistribution, that is a different thing again. An open-source example: It is OK to look at the code, and even create your own version of the original, or try to see what makes it work. It is, however, not legal to take the code, create the app and pass it off as your own.