# Decompile an apk file

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering, decompiler, recompile

How decompile an apk file and edit it and recompile it again??

Comment: What's the rationale behind this?

Comment: This is not you app !! is it ? :)

Comment: Have you tried www.google.com ?

Comment: oooo my god  thank u :| its realy helpful :| hilarious :|

Answer (score 1):

If you did not compile the apk or do not have the rights to access the source code, DO NOT ATTEMPT TO DO IT, it is illegal in many places.

That being said, if it is your apk and maybe you lost the original sources, you can decompile it with online tools:

http://www.decompileandroid.com/

or with a local tool:

https://apkstudio.codeplex.com/

But keep in mind that in order to upload an update to the play store, you also need the exact same signing certificate.

Comment: that's not work for me :( i want decompile a file at all , that site decompile just some parts of this app

Comment: Ask a lawyer if you want legal advice instead of trusting someone on the internet. Or at least double check whats legal in your jurisdiction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674557/is-it-legal-to-decompile-an-apk-and-use-part-of-its-code-in-your-app seems to suggest that at least decompiling is legal in the United States